# Megascans from Bridge - Why do all texture stretch and some don't even work? (Cycles)

Tags: texturing, materials

Most of the megascans that I exported from blender to Bridge are either stretched or don't work properly (no depth, or no color). Is there something I need to keep in mind?

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of an example material shader tree to see if something's wrong ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. As you can see, the textures are too big. The scratch marks on the pipe are very big. I do understand that this is because my whole scene is very small, but I was limited to this because of my 3D tacked cloudpoints. 

https://imgur.com/a/CUpFhmQ